# How can I identify issues with a shared cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

We are using Asp.net MVC 5 and the "new" ASP.Net Identity based Cookie authentication.

While using the security stack in multiple web sites sharing the same machine key, it can happen, that someone messes up the configuration in one of the web sites and the cryptography service cannot do its job anymore... throwing:

> Exception:Thrown: "Error occurred during a cryptographic operation." (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException)
>   A System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was thrown: "Error occurred during a cryptographic operation."

So that's not my issue, the behaviour is perfectly fine, my problem is, I'd like to at least log an exception somewhere or throw something at the user to indicate that the configuration has been messed up...

Unfortunately the asp.net owin middleware swallows all exceptions and just does redirect back to what ever is configured as the entry point of the application. Which is also fine...

Now question is, **how and where can I identify if this issue occurs** and do some logging etc...?

If I put a simple debug middleware like

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    try
    {
        await next.Invoke();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
});
```

of course the exception does not get thrown, and it also cannot be found in e.g. `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`...

Any ideas or hints are much appreciated!